# How to reload Iscroll after jqm datafilter change?

Tags: jquery-mobile, iscroll4

I have a listview with a jquerymobile datafilter and I'm using iscroll. After a search with the datafilter I would like to reload Iscroll since it doesn't resize the scrollable area.(So it's possible to scroll away from the items)

This is my html:

```
        <div id="mywrapper" class="wrapper">
            <div data-role="content" id="myscroller">
                <ul data-role="listview" id="lstvw_myitems" data-filter="true"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have already tried to bind a change event to the listvw_myitems change but it doesn't seem to get called.

This is what I've tried:

```
$('#lstvw_myitems').change(function() {
      loadIScroll('wrapper');
});
```

Are there any other (jquery)events I could try to catch on the listview?

This is the Iscroll code I use.(the timeout is to fix a bug when iscroll was loading,the other code is to prevent selecting while scrolling.)

```
function loadIScroll(wrapperId){
setTimeout(function () {
    var myScroll = new iScroll(wrapperId, {bounce: false, hScrollbar: false, vScrollbar: false, vScroll: true, useTransform: true, zoom: false,
        onBeforeScrollStart: function(e){
            var target = e.target;
            while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;
            if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA')
                e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    }, 1);
```

}

I'm using jqm 1.3 jq 1.9.1 and iscroll v4.2.5.

Comment: Are you using iScrol 4 or its jQuery Mobile version called iScrollView?

Comment: Could you please post your code in which you bind the `iScroller`

Comment: I think I'm using the normal iScroll4 and I've added the code from the loadIScroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stead of looking for events on the list object I have change my code to look for input in the search inputbox.

Here's an example:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow',"*", function(e, data){
//bind keypress of datafilter to resize iscroll
$('.ui-input-search > input').bind("keyup",function(){
    myScroll.refresh();
});
```

});

Notes:
Iscroll var has to be available in the scope to refresh it. This event is always called because of the * selector, using another selector would be better. I also don't know if the '.ui-input-search > input' selector is enough to cover only those search input boxes.

Maybe someone else will come up with a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

Im trying to do this as well. Its a long list and once someone enters data my Iscroll does not resize.  i tried your method and I am not 100% sure i understand. Any advice I would be greatful.

Here is my iscroll code:

```
  var myScroll;
var scroll_cookie = readCookie('scrollToAlt');
var back_cookie = readCookie('previousPagePath');
function loaded() 
   {
   myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper',
       {scrollbarClass: 'myScrollbar',
            hideScrollbar:false,
       });
        if ($('#scroller').height() <= $('#wrapper').height()){
           myScroll.destroy();
           myScroll = null;
        }
   }
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow',"*", function(e, data){
    //bind keypress of datafilter to resize iscroll
    $('.ui-input-search > input').bind("keyup",function(){
    myScroll.refresh();
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you're code doesn't destroy the Iscroll before the refresh?